# How to persist logged in user without going back?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks, react-router

I'm currently working on a web platform using React Js. I have stored backend token into my local storage but once the user signed in successfully then he should not go back with browser back arrow click. He should persist in the same page so how can I do it in react js? can I use useEffect hook there? Or I have to write any conditions for that? Only by clicking Logout button he should come back not with browser coming back arrow. Some people did it using componentDidMount but I'm in functional component so I used useEffect but It was not working. I tried multiple ways but unable to find solution. How can I achieve it in react js?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't, or shouldn't, a user be allowed to navigate back? Can you clarify the use case? Can you share what you've tried? What *specifically* is the issue? Back navigation or authentication state persistence? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yeah It means once the user is logged in then  if he clicked back button all log in state will be lost. So  I should stop the authenticated user coming back with browser back arrow only by clicking logout button he should come out not by browser arrow

Comment: If you wan't to replace the current url once the user has logged in, to prevent the user from going back, incase if you are using react router dom, you can use the ```navigate(to, { replace: true })``` for React Router V6 or ```history.replace(location)``` for React Router V5

Comment: You shouldn't prevent back navigation to not lose authentication state, you should move your authentication state higher up the ReactTree above your routing code. You should also persist it to localStorage or some longterm storage so it is also retained through page reloads. Please share what you've tried, and provide clear details on what isn't working as expected. We can't help diagnose and debug code we can't see.

Comment: Yeah But once the user signed in using the stored data my webpage going forward and backward without asking sign-in again

Comment: That is why you lift the state up above the routes and use protected routes. So long as the user is authenticated they can navigate freely where they are allowed. I'm starting to think this is really your question, how to create protected routes for your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a user context, where upon login the user information is stored in localStorage and in the context api.

```
const storeUser = ({user, token}) => {
  localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
  localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  setUserState((prevUserState) => ({ ...prevUserState, user, token}));
};
```

then your data will be persisted throughout the website as long as you implement your user context correctly. To be clear, if you implement the context correctly, pressing back won't clear the localStorage or user state.

I'm afraid that if you try and implement it in a functional component by itself, the data will be wiped on re-render.

If you want to check whether or not a user has signed in then you can modify your site to allow access only to users that have signed in, by either coding it inline

```
{user.singedIn ? (<h1>Hello user</h1>) : (<h1>please sign in</h1>)
```

or in your routes

```
<Route path='/' element={!user ? <Navigate replace to='/login' /> : <Home />} />
```

Comment: But the problem is by using that data If once I signed in then after coming out also It's going directly to my dashboard without asking re singin after sometimes. So If it directly let the user in through the browser forward and backward button means what is the use of login authentication?

Comment: see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a protective route function, store the token you're getting in your local storage and give a condition that those not allow the user to see the signin page as long as the token is available, then you can clear the token from your local storage in your handlelogout